# Angular Smart Tables st-sort function with parameters

Tags: angularjs, sorting, smart-table

I'm currently trying to use the sort functionality with smart tables.  Currently the setup we have is what we are passing to smart tables is just an identifier (this is not the real example - so ignore if this certain example can be optimized, its hypothetical to get the point across):

```
[{'id': 1},{'id':4},{'id': 3},{'id':4} }]
```

Now based on this, we display say the type in 1 column and a description in another. Both of these are looked up in a different object. I'd like to know how can I sort using a generic getter function that I can pass the object lookup to sort on instead of creating several customized getter functions.

Right now I have to do this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th st-sort="sortByTypeDescription">
       </th>
       <th st-sort="sortByTypeName">
       </th>
    </tr>
</table>

$scope.sortByTypeDescription = function(row) {
      return $scope.descriptions[row.id].description;
}

$scope.sortByTypeName = function(row) {
      return $scope.name[row.id].name;
}
```

I was wondering if there is something like this I can do OR send in the extra parameters in a separate attribute so the function is dynamic:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th st-sort="sortColumn(descriptions,description)">
       </th>
       <th st-sort="sortColumn(name,name)">
       </th>
    </tr>
</table>

$scope.sortByTypeName = function(row,a,b) {
      return $scope.[a][row.id][b];
}
```

Comment: There's an example of custom sort function right in docs. Look at `getters.firstName` example

Comment: @charlietfl I don't see this in the doc, can you clarify where?  All I see is you can declare a function but no reference to parameters.

Comment: @charlietfl yes getters.firstName is a custom function but I can't send parameters. for example: getters.firstName(firstParam,secondParam) which is what my question is referencing.

Comment: you have the object available inside function....why can't you use it to lookup whatever in controller?

Answer (score 0):

From @charlietfl's comment:
Take a look at the example at [smart-tables' doc](https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) using the getter-example. For your case, you could do this:

```
$scope.getters={
    sortByTypeDescription: function (row) {
        return $scope.descriptions[row.id].description;
    }
}
```

and in the html:

```
<tr>
    <th st-sort="getters.sortByTypeDescription"></th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return function:

```
$scope.sortByTypeName = function(a,b) {
    return function (row) {
        $scope[a][row.id][b];
    }
}
```